# Prove that for any constant we may obtain $x_n$ : $f(x_n + C) - f(x_n) \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous bounded on $(a,+\infty)$. We want to prove that then $\forall C > 0$ there is exist $\{x_n\}$ : $f(x_n + C) - f(x_n) \to 0$.

I thought that's easy problem. My idea was about that we may find $y = l$, for which there is infinite intersections with $f(x)$ on $(a,+\infty)$, but  I've constructed a bounded continuous function, for which I couldn't find such $y = l$.

Also I've tried to contradiction. Supposed that there is a $C$(for example $C=1)$ : $\forall \{x_n\}$ we have $f(x_n + 1) - f(x_n) \not \to 0$.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you show the function you've constructed?

Comment: @saulspatz it can be drawn on plane using parts of $\frac{1}{2^n} \sin(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r\equiv \inf_{x>\frac a C} |f((x+1)C)-f(xC)| >0$ then $f((x+1)C)-f(xC)$ is  continuous function which never vanishes. Hence it does not change signs. Suppose it is always positive. Then  $f((n+1)C) \geq nr+f(C)$ which makes $f$ unbounded. Hence $r= 0$. A similar argument holds when the function is always negative. Thus $r=0$. This proves the existence of a sequence $(y_k)$ such that $f(y_kC+C)-f(x_kC) \to 0$. Take $x_k=Cy_k$.